# a doubt on free group in Dummit&Foote's Abstract Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups

I have a doubt about free group in Dummit's Abstract Algebra on page220 :

> More generally, suppose $G$ is presented by, say, generators $a, b$ with relations $r_1 , . . . , r_k$ . If $a', b'$ are any elements of a group $H$ satisfying these relations, there is a homomorphism from $G$ into $H$ . Namely, if $\pi : F(\{a, b\}) \to G$ is the presentation homomorphism, we can define $\pi' : F(\{a, b\}) \to H$ by $\pi ' (a) = a'$ and $\pi' (b) = b'$ . Then ${\color{red}{\ker \pi \leq \ker \pi'}}$ so $\pi'$ factors through $\ker \pi$ and we obtain

$$
G\cong F(\{a,b\})/\ker\pi\to H\ .
$$

In the text, $F(\{a,b\})$ means the free group on the set $\{a,b\}$ . My doubt is that how can we get " $\ker\pi\leq\ker\pi'$ ", or I think it is more exactly to write " $\ker\pi=\ker\pi'$ " : $\pi(a)=a,\pi(b)=b,\pi'(a)=a',\pi'(b)=b'$ together with the fact that $a,b$ and $a',b'$ have the same relations, must imply that $\ker\pi=\ker\pi'$ . Is my thought correct or false?

Comment: $H$ could satisfy additional relations, not just $r_1,\dots, r_k$, and then the two kernels could be different.

Answer (score 4):

Here $H$ is an arbitrary group with some elements that satisfy *at least* the relations that define $G$.  It isn't just another version of $G$.  It can have other elements/relations outside of the patterns that define $G$.

For example, suppose $G$ is presented by a single generator $a$ with the single relation $4a = 0$ (I'm using additive notation rather than multiplicative notation for what follows).  Then $G$ is a cyclic group of order 4 (i.e. $G \cong \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$).

Let $H = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$, and consider the element $a' = (1, 1, 0) \in H$.  Note that this element satisfies the relation in $G$'s presentation.

The claim is that the homomorphism $\pi': \langle a \rangle \rightarrow H$ given by $a \mapsto a'$ factors through $\ker \pi$, which works because $4\mathbb{Z}a = \ker \pi \le \ker \pi' = 2\mathbb{Z}a$.

So we get a homomorphism from $G\cong \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ to $H = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$ (with $1 \mapsto (1, 1, 0)$) just because the given element of $H$ satisfies the defining relation of $G$.

My choice of $H$ here was unnecessarily complicated - I just wanted to demonstrate that $H$ doesn't have to have the same number of generators (mine isn't cyclic like $G$) and can have parts that are totally ignored by the image of the homomorphism (like the $\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$ component here).

Comment: Your answer helps me realize this fact: the dihedral group $D_4$ has the same relations with $D_8$ but since a presentation means the largest group which generated by $s,r$ satisfying the relations $s^2=r^4=srsr=1$ , $\langle s,r\ |\ s^2=r^4=srsr=1\rangle\neq D_4$ . In the past I misunderstood the relation $r^n$ in the presentation refered to $|r|=n$ , and hence I thought that $|G|\leq|H|$ and then $\ker\pi$ must equal $\ker\pi'$ . Your example correct my mistake. But now I still do not know how to show $\ker\pi\leq\ker\pi'$ in a strict way. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Could you help me check if this idea can reach the desired result: $\ker\pi=\langle frf^{-1}\ |\ f\in F(S),r\in R\rangle$ , and since $H$ has additional relations, so $\ker\pi\leq\ker\pi'$ .

Comment: That seems like the right idea to me.  The point is that $\ker \pi$ is the normal closure of the relations defining $G$ (which is what you wrote).  Since the specified elements of $H$ satisfy at least those relations, $R \subset \ker \pi'$.  But $\ker \pi'$ is normal, so it contains the normal closure of $R$ (i.e. $\ker \pi$).